# How to write a global function which can be used by both service worker and vue components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have created a mixin method to perform a complex string manipulation operation. It is used by different components in my application. Now I need to use the same method inside my service worker file. How can I access the mixin method in *src -> mixins -> my-mixin.js* inside my service worker file which is located in *src -> sw.js*

If mixin is not the right way to solve this problem, how can I solve this requirement? A global function which can be used by both service worker file and vue components.

I’m using webpack 3.12

Comment: Does your current config allow you to simply `require`/`import` it?

Comment: simple `import myMixin from './mixins/my-mixin'` didn't work for me.

Comment: Does your mixin depend on external state that is directly available in browser but might not be directly available in a service worker (eg. `document`)?

Comment: No. It is just a string formatting function. I will send a json object and it will return a string. As simple as that.

Comment: Could you describe the problem that you have when trying to import it?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. in the line `import myMixin from './mixins/my-mixin'`

Comment: Unless your browser supports imports, you should use a transpiler alongside your bundler (or use `require` with webpack since it manages it)

Comment: Just think in simple way. Your mixin is js file which containing an object and `export default ...` with methods or whatever inside.
You can use keyword `import` or `required` to link it to your service worker and use it.